# SED change value in file

Tags: regex, sed

Again question about SED. So I have log file:

```
#######################################
################start host1############
#######################################
##java serv
host1,def,java,es,dev L2,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev L3,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev M1,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev M4,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev N1,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev M5,0,dev w,fr


##c++ serv
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev L2,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev L3,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev M1,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev M4,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev N1,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev M5,0,dev w,fr
#######################################
################end host1##############
#######################################

#######################################
################start host2############
#######################################
##java serv
host2,def,java,es,dev L2,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,java,es,dev L3,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,java,es,dev M1,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,java,es,dev M4,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,java,es,dev N1,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,java,es,dev M5,0,dev w,fr


##c++ serv
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev L2,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev L3,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev M1,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev M4,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev N1,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev M5,0,dev w,fr
#######################################
################end host2##############
#######################################
```

How can I change value from 0 to 1 after L2 symbol in section "host1", tags "java" and "c++"? This variant doesn't work for me:

```
  sed  '/start host1/,/end host1/s/,L2,0,/L2,1,/g' file
```

And another question. How to change this value only in java tag and only in c++ tag in "host1" section. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this,

```
sed '/start host1/,/end host1/{s/\(host1,def,java,es,dev \)L2,0/\1L2,1/g}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to get you started:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=',' '/host1,def,java,es,dev L2/{$6=1}1' input
```